# PHP execution time: Factor to consider in determining the speed to execution

Tags: php, memcached, profile, execution

As all my requests goes through an index script, I tried to time the respond time of all my requests.

Its simply the difference between the start time (start of the script) and end time (end of the script).

As I cache my data on memcached and user are all served using memcached.

I mostly get less than a second respond time but at times there's wierd spike of more than a seconds. the worse case can go up to 200+ seconds.

I was wondering if mobile users had a slow connection, does that reflect on my respond time?

I am serving primary mobile users.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're measuring in PHP (which it sounds like you are), thats the time it takes for the page to be generated on the server side, not the time it takes to be downloaded.

Drop timers in throughout the page, and try and break it down to a section that is causing the huge delay of 200+ seconds.

You could even add a small script that will email you details of how long each section took to load if it doesn't happen often enough to see it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am guessing it might be EC2 happen to pick on that particular php execution and decide to be bias against it. As about 90+% of the request are less than a second. I will continue to monitor the situation. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, it's the runtime of your script. It does not count the latency to the user, that's something the underlying web server is worrying about. Something in your script just takes very long. I recommend you profile your script to find what that is. [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) is a good way to do so.

Comment: Thanks! For the quick answer guys. :) I wish I could vote you guys up.

Comment: @lxcid In fact, you *can*. And you should accept an answer, too.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the script cannot finish because a client downloads the results very-very slowly. If you don't use a front-end server like **nginx**, the first thing to do is to try it.

Comment: Not true.  A script doesn't start until the request is received, and it is completely generated regardless of how long it takes the client to download.

Nginx is helpful for caching to an extent though, but the OP still needs to figure out what the source of the problem is.

The only way I would accept this explanation is if the user was uploading files, and then nginx wouldn't even help.

Answer (score 0):

Someone already mentioned xdebug, but normally you would not want to run xdebug in production. I would suggest using [xhprof](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.xhprof.php) to profile pages on development/staging/production. You can turn on xhprof conditionally, which makes it really easy to run on production.